# Update value of the object which is inherited by str class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, str-replace

I have a class which inherits from `str`:

```
class Gender(str):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.VALIDATION_META = {"valid": None, "errors": list()}
        self.gender = str()
```

Now I create an object with some value.
`obj = Gender('Male')`
How I can replace the value only within the object.

e.g obj = 'Female' object type should be the Gender

Comment: You have to assign to `obj.gender`, either directory or by using a method which assigns to `self.gender`. It's not clear why `Gender` is inheriting from `str` here: `Gender` is not a kind of `str`, and you appear to be using the `str`-valued `gender` attribute in lieu of the objects own "inherent" value.

Comment: It's also not clear why the signature of `__init__` is so general: what arguments do you expect aside from the `str`-valued gender label?

Comment: If the value you want to use is something different from the underlying value of the `str` (which is immutable), then it is pointless to inherit from `str` - all of the existing methods will look only at that underlying value, and pay no attention to your value.  And if you do want to use the underlying value, you have to specify it in `.__new__()`, it's far too late to change it in `.__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

simply put one more line of code at the end as in

```py
obj = Gender('Male')
obj.gender = "Female"
```

please pay attention: if you still print obj it will print "Male" not "Female" because you changed the internal variable of object not its method that prints the value.
i.e.

```py
>>> print(obj)
'Male'
>>> print(obj.gender)
'Female'
```